# Here's precisely what I am not. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

At first I’m quite fun to be around,

until I make some wrongful sound.

Maybe it offends, maybe it’s rude

but I conceal my true attitude.

---

Reverse me and you’ve something new

be it a weapon, or a cold, cold bar,

a means of relocation, near or far,

it’s something you’d be daft to chew!

---

Interested in becoming me?

If you aren’t already, all it takes to be

is to toughen up, brace yourself, grin --

then declare “I am one, and always have been!”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unsure, but I think you are

> an honest person

From what you are not :

> **At first I’m quite fun to be around,**
>
> **until I make some wrongful sound.**
>
> ==> liars can be fun before they are found out
> **Maybe it offends, maybe it’s rude**
>
> **but I conceal my true attitude.**
>
> ==> Liars don't want to be found out even though lies can be offensive or rude
> **Reverse me and you’ve something new**
>
> ==> "liar" reversed becomes "rail"
> **be it a weapon, or a cold, cold bar,**
>
> ==> a rail-gun, or (unsure about the cold part) railing
> **a means of relocation, near or far,**
>
> ==> railroad tracks
> **it’s something you’d be daft to chew!**
>
> ==> See "railroad"... try biting on that!
> **Interested in becoming me?**
>
> **If you aren’t already, all it takes to be**
>
> **is to toughen up, brace yourself, grin --**
>
> **then declare “I am one, and always have been!”**
>
> ==>“I am one, and always have been!” :)

Then again, as pointed out by @Geobits

> The poem points to "liar". Which would mean you are one, and are actually lying about the poem being what you are not.

Therefore :

> A liar!

Comment: I think the overall answer is the opposite. That would make "Here's what I am not" a lie. Plus, you can't "become" honest by saying you always have been. "If you aren't already", then that would make that last statement a lie.

Comment: Aaah, good point. I'll edit that

Comment: @Geobits: Good catch! I was hoping that would throw someone off a bit because of the confusing logic involved. I'll mark this as an answer once you change it, karhell ^_^

Comment: There. Done... Though, I'm not quite satisfied with my wording >.<